# Hilbert transform and maximal function

Tags: harmonic-analysis

What is the relation between the Hilbert transform (in $\mathbb{R}$) and maximal functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, the real Hardy space $H^1(\mathbb R)$ can be described in two equivalent ways:

- the space of functions $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ such that the Hilbert transform of $f$ also belongs to $L^1$
- the space of functions $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ such that the maximal function $\sup_t (f*\Phi_t)$ also belongs to $L^1(\mathbb R)$. Here $\Phi_t=t^{-n}\Phi(x/t)$ and $\Phi$ can be any Schwarz function.

The Hardy-Littlewood maximal function does not have such a direct relation, since it looks only at the amplitude $|f|$, ignoring the sign.

Comment: What is $\Phi_t$? Also, can you elaborate on your last comment?

Comment: @Anonymous999 I added the definition of $\Phi_t$. I feel disinclined to elaborate further on the answer, seeing how little effort went into the question.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyways.